# i want to write a tool that generates c# class objects from json

Tags: c#, json

I want to write a tool to convert JSON and generate the c# class from JSON  object like json2csharp.com I want to know how to proceed with creating a tool

is there any class that helps in creating or any such things.

Comment: json.net, Code Dom, also this is too broad. Please read the help on asking a question

Comment: Visual studio can help you with it : Edit-> paste special menu.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio already has a built in feature.  Simply copy the JSON into the clipboard and paste into Visual Studio via **Edit.Paste Special.Paste JSON as Classes**.

[image]